# Expresso Store DPS/PxPay Response Issues

Tags: expresso-store

When using PaymentExpress_PxPay on my Expresso Store, it all works fine until I get returned from DPS with the below URL.

```
/?ACT=30&H=5c08b9f81972472bd8f0a7691a82388c?result=v5Z1giv_jYce6gai7Ng6XIMCiiGkz5I43snkE6WWVwfMmZMy9iGlWiDp3v4fiv-qYrY9n4YCoX8GC0QnrXLmu95MKZ16QRPLhNgzm7Glv3riSlyGCVNOHGdxSEQLDGxveHs6chn3pdo-osy1ElCqxlvCVBlp7t5P7g7MRsEnUS3tK2sR6tvuCOrkFZJ71reJGDn6jeqEq6LYz20vdeZPF3TtPHPAQaD5hX0_sSJ2fDnMESgsiupFvv5mU4zNoNXL5OlUxR4Z34Jq-ZNyK--NEvcGk8zZHvOkouriaVeeKhhJjCCB8SX64lCeyDgcsfRkofXcx2Qnr4R6qV2qjZkTt2YmdviXQCwxqzKRR5g-ZPTgiZTXn6bu68YE6fzCN94O1K_pFCO4aZ2lN2NR35Ced8eW41LuIkI4VDZYFvXOaG-h7EVETm3XWTARVm-f_rgtyyxwbAi2kJBrfMsp4w59KZx13ACqBRje6-&userid={my DPS user id}
```

Store can't extract the transaction hash out of the get data. (In Module.php, act_payment_return()) It looks for the index "H" which you can see below, but that drags "?result" and all the rest with it two as it's not properly. I seem to remember having some strange issues with processing DPS responses in the past when building my own payment processors, but as this is an out of the box product where this is already built I thought I better see if anyone else has had this issue.

EE V2.7.2, Store V2.0.6

Comment: There is a known issue with DPS return URLs in the current version of Store - please email support@exp-resso.com and we will get you a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue has been resolved in Store v2.20. If you upgrade to the current latest version you shouldn't have any problems.

Alternatively if you're using EE 2.7 then set "Process form data in Secure Mode" to "No" in Admin > Security & Privacy > Security & Sessions in the control panel.

Comment: Hi Ian. Thanks for the response. I don't believe that's the issue as I've already got secure forms disabled. Upgrading at this stage is possibly not really an option as I'd have to upgrade EE as well. I'll save that as a last resort. Thanks again.

Comment: I've upgraded to EE 2.8.1 and Store 2.3.1. The issue still exists. After coming back from DPS I just get dumped on an EE error page saying "There was an unexpected error while processing your order.".

Comment: This issue appears to be resolved on EE 2.9.2 and Store 2.4.1 (for the most part). The "payment_return" page throws a notice of "Use of undefined constant CSRF_TOKEN - assumed 'CSRF_TOKEN'" if you have php errors enabled and you have to refresh the page to proceed.